# Using %in% to filter rows based on Chromosome AND Position

Tags: r, dplyr, vcf-variant-call-format

I have two dataframes: one is VCF with genotype information, the other is a dataframe of "special" SNP positions. **Using dplyr**, I'd like to filter the VCF for only those positions that exist in the dataframe of special SNPs, however, I can't figure out how to use %in% for multiple columns.

VCF dataframe:

```
CHR   POS   REF   ALT
01    10    C     T
01    20    G     A
01    30    T     C
02    20    A     G
02    30    C     G
02    40    G     T
02    50    T     A
```

SPECIAL_SNP dataframe:

```
CHR   POS
01    20
01    30
02    40
02    50
```

Desired Output:

```
CHR   POS   REF   ALT
01    20    G     A
01    30    T     C
02    40    G     T
02    50    T     A
```

I was thinking something similar to this:

```
VCF %>%
    filter(.[, c("CHR", "POS"] %in% SPECIAL_SNP[, c("CHR", "POS")])
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `inner_join`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(VCF, SPECIAL_SNP)
#   CHR POS REF ALT
#1   1  20   G   A
#2   1  30   T   C
#3   2  40   G   T
#4   2  50   T   A
```

---

Or another option is `%in%`

```
VCF[do.call(paste, VCF[1:2]) %in% do.call(paste, SPECIAL_SNP[1:2]),]
```

#### data

```
VCF <- structure(list(CHR = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), POS = c(10L, 
20L, 30L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L), REF = c("C", "G", "T", "A", "C", 
"G", "T"), ALT = c("T", "A", "C", "G", "G", "T", "A")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

SPECIAL_SNP <- structure(list(CHR = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), POS = c(20L, 30L, 40L, 
50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @akrun. Unfortunately, I'm working with very large dataframes, so joining seems to be very slow. Is there another way to do this using filter()?

Comment: @nad7wf  Can you try with the `%in%` with `paste`

Comment: The %in% solution is perfect. Thanks @akrun.